# How to match multiple multi-line python function definitions separately

Tags: python, regex

I have been struggling to write a regex that can match what I want.

I want to be able to parse an entire python source file and, for that file, get a list of all of the function definitions.

I wrote some example text to parse, trying to take in all the various complexities that can be in a function def for python:

```
def New_function_withSomestuff10(test: str, thing: str,
                                 third: float, last=a(10): int) -> str:
    test

def stuff(things):
    stuff

def New_function_withSomestuff11(test: str, thing: str,
                                 third: float, last: int) -> str:
    test
```

I have a current Regex that seems to match these fine, but it seems to match all of them:

```
regex = r'def (?P<name>\w*)\([\s\S]*\):[\s\S]*'
```

The "name" capture group only returns with "New_function_withSomestuff10", and everything after that capture group grabs EVERYTHING to the end of the sample text.

My hope is to get

```
re.findall(regex, sample_text)
-> ['New_function_withSomestuff10', 'stuff', 'New_function_withSomestuff11']
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?  I have been trying to wrap my head around greedy vs lazy quantifiers, lookahead/lookbehind, and other such useful tools, but none of them seem to do what I need (or, more likely, I'm just using them wrong).

Comment: Among other things, functions in Python can be nested (a function within a function), and regular expressions cannot match recursive structures.

Comment: only a function name without arguments?

Comment: @DYZ I am not concerned with recursive structures, but this current regex detects all functions TOGETHER, instead of just detecting the first one.  The ":" near the end of the regex, which should match the end of the first function, is matching the end of the LAST function in the file.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest In terms of what I want out of the regex, yes I only care about the name in the end, but I imagine that the regex needs to match any possible parameters as well in order to properly find the function definitions.

Comment: You still must balance the parentheses, and it's a recursive task.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below will help:

```
regex=r"def (?P<name>\w+)\(.*?\)"
re.findall(regex, sample_text, re.DOTALL)

#['New_function_withSomestuff10', 'stuff', 'New_function_withSomestuff11']
```

Explanation:

`Regex: def (?P<name>\w+)\(.*?\)`

- **def**  matches the characters def  literally (case sensitive)
- Named Capture Group *name* **(?P<name>\w+)**

  - **\w** matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
  - **+ Quantifier** — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- **(** matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
- **.*?** matches any character

  - ***?** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- **)** matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)

`Flag: re.DOTALL`

- If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.